# Tree shaking: are unused functions included to a bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollupjs, parceljs, tree-shaking

Do modern bundlers like Webpack or Rollup shake out only unused modules or are they capable of removing unused functions (or variables, classes) inside a module as well?

```
// src.js
export function unused() {}
export function used() {} 

// bundle.js
// function unused() {}  // <-- will this be included?
function used() {}
```

Searched on the subject but found nothing.

P.S. I've no experience with bundlers (other than zero-config Parcel) but I make the library that requires the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I've searched not well enough.

Here: https://medium.com/@netxm/what-is-tree-shaking-de7c6be5cadd
the author says that unused functions won't be included.